# CSS Why my code don't work?

Tags: css

HTML

```
<div id="galerie">
    <div id="stanga">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#galerie {
    margin-top: 5%;
    width: 974px;
    height: 500px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:yellow;
}
#stanga {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

I want my red square to have `margin-top:10px` from the yellow container.
http://jsfiddle.net/97fzwuxh/16/

Answer (score 2):

Margins will collapse by design, So your inner margin have effect on your outer div.

add `overflow:auto` to your `#galerie` style

or

add `padding:1px` to your `#galerie` style

Your problem is called `adjoining`

Two margins are `adjoinin` of a box and top margin of its first in-flow child, if both belong to vertically-adjacent box edges

Answer (score 0):

The margins are not working because they are collapsing, use:

```
position: relative;
top: 20px;
```

Here the updated fiddle: "http://jsfiddle.net/97fzwuxh/18/"

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute for this.

```
#galerie {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 5%;
    width: 974px;
    height: 500px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:yellow;
}

#stanga {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need position: relative on the outer element(#galerie)
and position: absolute on the inner element(#stanga)

```
#galerie {
    width: 974px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color:yellow;
    position: relative;
}

#stanga {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-top:200px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Here is the updated working fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/97fzwuxh/19/

Also, read this article I found it very useful: https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

TLDR: A page element with relative positioning gives you the control to absolutely position children elements inside of it.